# Error when using Kibanas terms_stats panel

Tags: kibana

I ran into an error with the terms_stats panel in Kibana. Whenever I try to add it - and seemingly regardless of the settings - I get the following:

```
Error: b.results.facets is undefined
```

Followed by the stacktrace:

```
Error: b.results.facets is undefined
g@http://kibana/app/panels/terms/module.js?r=3.1.0-23cd70f:4:2561
h@http://kibana/app/panels/terms/module.js?r=3.1.0-23cd70f:4:3065
.link/<@http://kibana/app/panels/terms/module.js?r=3.1.0-23cd70f:4:4260
ic/this.$get</f.prototype.$broadcast@http://kibana/app/app.js?r=3.1.0-23cd70f:9:7893
@http://kibana/app/app.js?r=3.1.0-23cd70f:22:14242
$.event.dispatch@http://kibana/app/app.js?r=3.1.0-23cd70f:5:5561
$.event.add/h@http://kibana/app/app.js?r=3.1.0-23cd70f:5:1529
```

Have any of you run into this before, and do you have any suggestions for solutions?

I am using Kibana version 3.0.1 and Elasticsearch version 1.3.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your version of Kibana and Elasticsearch?

Comment: Naturally! I've added them to the post :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any answers, but the issue is deprecated. Closing.